# Too many redirects while setting up gogs with nginx

Tags: nginx, gogs

I am setting up gogs on nginx server.I also have cpanel/apache hosted on the same server.I am redirecting my gogs call using .htaccess from cpanel.My nginx configuration is

```
server {
    listen 9800;
    server_name <my_domain>;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; # pass on real client IP

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

It is working fine if i am using direct ip from browser but when i am using domain it throwing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error on browser.